# MVC WebGrid Set the ID rendered

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid

Using WebGrid from MVC 3 how do i specify the name of the control when rendered i.e. the id of the table when rendered??

```
var someGrid = new WebGrid(source: Model.Users, defaultSort: "Name", rowsPerPage: 50);
```

At the moment when rendered as a table it is displaying as

```
<table class="grid">
```

with no id set, i want to access this table using jQuery id selector but cant. Any help appreciated.

What i want is `<table id="someIDWhichIset">`

Thanks
Niall

Answer (score 26):

when you're rendering your table is when you give it the id.
`@someGrid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new {id ="someIDWhichIset"}, columns: ....`

Comment: @NBrowne This answer is exactly what you have asked for, please accept this answer.