# How to add Id for @Html.Grid rows in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, nopcommerce

How to add Id field for the @Html.Grid in MVC,my code is given below

```
  @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(column =>
       {
           column.For(rph => rph.SpecificationAttributeOption).Named("").Attributes(style => "width:70%;");
       }).Attributes(style => "width: 100%; border: 0px").RowStart((row) =>
       {
           if (row.IsAlternate) { return "<tr style=''>"; }
           else { return "<tr>"; }
       })
```

Comment: @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(column=>{}).Attributes(id =>"id-of-your-choice")

Answer (score 0):

I can not take credit for this, but I can sure pass one I found along to you.  It appears as though you can/should add an ID via the "HTML Attributes" setting, as in `new {id ="someIDWhichIset"}`;

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989958/mvc-webgrid-set-the-id-rendered) StackOverflow answer.